# get rid of rectangle around rouded boxes

Tags: html, css

I've a text area in my html, and this has rounded edges. but when I click inside the text area, it is showing a rectangle around the rounded edges.

Below is my HTML.

```
<textarea placeholder="Enter Text Here..." id="usermsg" class="Textareausermsg" onclick="TextAreaToggle()" style="margin: 0px 0px 0px -50px; width: 490px; height: 41px;"></textarea>
```

and here is my CSS

```
.Textareausermsg {
    border-radius: 15px;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 34px;
}
```

working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/jrss9192/1/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just remove the outline

```
.Textareausermsg {
    border-radius: 15px;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 34px;
    outline: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The rectangle that you are seeing is a browser-default outline. While its not a good idea to remove browser default styles, it can be done by declaring outline: none;

```css
.Textareausermsg {
    border-radius: 15px;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 34px;
    outline: none;
}
```

```html
<textarea placeholder="Enter Text Here..." id="usermsg" class="Textareausermsg" style="margin: 0px 0px 0px -50px; width: 490px; height: 41px;"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use: `outline: none` when the textarea is focused

```
  textarea:focus{
    outline: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's outline of `textarea` appears on `focus` just set `outline:0;` on `.Textareausermsg`

```css
.Textareausermsg {
    border-radius: 15px;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 34px;
    outline:0;
}
```

```html
<textarea placeholder="Enter Text Here..." id="usermsg" class="Textareausermsg" style="width: 260px; height: 41px;"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

The rectangled area is called "outline" and it's a css property.
Try add `outline: none;` in your css code to remove it.

If you want a "blue border" when you click / focus the element, try this

```
.Textareausermsg {
    border-radius: 15px;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 34px;
    outline: none;
}

.Textareausermsg:focus, .Textareausermsg:active {
    border:1px solid blue;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jrss9192/2/

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution to your question.

```
 .Textareausermsg {
        border-radius: 15px;
        font-size: 15px;
        text-align: left;
        line-height: 34px;
        outline: none;
    }
    .Textareausermsg :active , .Textareausermsg :focus { outline:none}
```